# Proving convergence of series, what test should I use?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Prove the convergence or divergence of the following series

A) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(n+1)^{100}}{n!}$

B) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{n}{n-1})^n$

C) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(\frac{n}{10})^n$

In A) I tried using the ratio test, but I didn't get anything because I don't what to do with the exponent

In B) and C) I don't know what test I should use...

Comment: The ratio test should work for A, what exactly did you compute? – For B and C: what is a *simple necessary* criterion for the convergence of a series?

Comment: FOr b) you have trivially $$ \left( \frac{n}{n-1} \right)^n \ge 1$$ For c) you can simply use the root test.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of different techniques that you could use for this question. As a general strategy for working with sequences and series, I think that the comparison test should be your first go-to after the divergence test: even if you cannot conclusively prove whether the sequence converges or diverges using the comparison, it does help shed some light on how the series behaves. Try fiddling with the items inside the summand to make them (a) larger if you suspect that the series converges or (b) smaller if you suspect the series diverges. For example in part your question (C), with a little fiddling, you can see that the sequence eventually gets bigger than $\sum\left(\frac{11}{10}\right)^n$ (I have intentionally omitted the bounds here). What nice type of series does this look like? What do you know about this series?

Answer (score 0):

(A)

The first candidate should be the ratio test as you suggested.
\begin{align}
\dfrac{\frac{(n+2)^{100}}{(n+1)!}}{\frac{(n+1)^{100}}{n!}}
&= \left(\dfrac{n+2}{n+1}\right)^{100}\dfrac{n!}{(n+1)!}\\
&= \left(\dfrac{n+2}{n+1}\right)^{100}\dfrac{n!}{(n+1)!}\\
&= \left(1+\dfrac{1}{n+1}\right)^{100}\dfrac{1}{n+1}\\
&\to0
\end{align}
as $n\to\infty$

(B) and (C): Check $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$! (exclamation, not factorial)